# A 400 error occurs when creating a OneDrive API upload session

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

Create an upload session to upload large files to oneDrive.

Below is the request address.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userId}/drive/root:/UploadFiles/{fileName}:/createUploadSession](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%7BuserId%7D/drive/root:/UploadFiles/%7BfileName%7D:/createUploadSession)

Request Body

```
  {
 "item": {
"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.driveItemUploadableProperties",
"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename",
"name": "largefile.dat"
 }
}
```

An Invalid request error occurs. What's wrong with it? I watched the tutorial and tested it.

POST /drive/root:/{item-path}:/createUploadSession
Content-Type: application/json

```
{
"item": {
"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.driveItemUploadableProperties",
"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename",
"name": "largefile.dat"
}
```

}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-beta#create-an-upload-session

Comment: The `400` response should include a JSON body with details of the failure - do you have an example?

Comment: @Brad {
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Invalid request",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-10-15T04:24:49",
            "request-id": "2733aaad-cb81-4762-acb5-cc069b44ddb2",
            "client-request-id": "3cd178ab-3315-c047-cab8-20b1c8166ec4"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Please remove the odata.type property and give it a try. It worked for me.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma can hv a look at this too? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77894809/uploading-big-files-to-sharepoint-via-create-upload-session-and-it-returns-501

Answer (score 2):

As Shiva suggested in a comment on the question, the issue is that the value of `@odata.type` is not correct for this case. In general you should not provide it at all as the schema is strongly typed and therefore the appropriate value can be derived without any client-driven hints.

Comment: var jObject = JObject.FromObject(new { item = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "rename" } }, fileSystemInfo = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@odata.type", "microsoft.graph.fileSystemInfo" } }, name = fileName });
     var toJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject);
     var content = new StringContent(toJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

     var response = await _client.PostAsync("users/"+ upn + "/drive/root:/MailFiles/" + fileName +":/createUploadSession", content);

Comment: If requested as above, it will run successfully. However, if the file is converted to bytes and sent to the upload session, the file is corrupted and uploaded.

Comment: Perhaps the docs should be updated as the example contains this data field: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: @brad can have a look at this too  -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77894809/uploading-big-files-to-sharepoint-via-create-upload-session-and-it-returns-501 ?