# Uploading big files to sharepoint via create upload session and it returns 501

Tags: java, spring-boot, sharepoint, file-upload, microsoft-graph-api

```
  public void uploadFileToSharePointNEW(File inputFile, String spoPath) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        //OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .sslSocketFactory(createInsecureSslSocketFactory(), new TrustAllCerts())
                .hostnameVerifier(new TrustAllHostnames())
                .build();
        System.out.println("NEWWWWWW ");
        String accessToken = this.oauthService.getAccessToken().getAccessToken();
        int CHUNK_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5 MB

        String uploadSessionUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/"+ siteId+"/Drives/"+driveId+"/root:/"+ spoPath +"/"+inputFile.getName()+":/createUploadSession";
//                .replace("{site-id}", siteId)
//                .replace("{drive-id}", driveId)
//                .replace("{folder-path}", folderPath)
//                .replace("{file-name}", fileName);

        // Step 1: Create an upload session
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), "{\"item\": {}}");
        System.out.println(requestBody);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(uploadSessionUrl)
                .post(requestBody)
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String responseBody = response.body().string();
        response.close();
       // String uploadUrl = new JSONObject(responseBody).getString("uploadUrl");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Map<String, ?> responseMap = gson.fromJson(responseBody, Map.class);
        System.out.println(responseMap);
        String uploadUrl = (String) responseMap.get("uploadUrl");
        System.out.println(uploadUrl);

        // Step 2: Upload the file in chunks
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        int offset = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("byte read going on");
            RequestBody chunkBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(uploadUrl)
                    .put(chunkBody)
                    .addHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(bytesRead))
                    .addHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + offset + "-" + (offset + bytesRead - 1) + "/" + inputFile.length())
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                    .build();
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            System.out.println(response);
            response.close();
            offset += bytesRead;
        }

        // Step 3: Commit the upload session
        System.out.println("Commit the upload session");
        requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), "{\"fileSystemInfo\": {}}");
        request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(uploadUrl)
//                .method("PATCH", requestBody)
                .method("PATCH", requestBody)
                .addHeader("Content-Length", "0")
                .addHeader("Content-Range", "bytes */" + inputFile.length())
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                .build();
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println(response);
        response.close();
    }
```

I have the following code which uploads big files to sharepoint, I get the upload url and get 200 for it, but the subsequent commit requesr returns a 501 not implemented error , i cannot understand why

anyone know whether there is a error in my code ?

error is as follows

```
{@odata.context=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.uploadSession, expirationDateTime=2024-01-28T12:44:55.401Z, nextExpectedRanges=[0-], uploadUrl=https://x.sharepoint.com/sites/PrivateMarket/_api/v2.0/drives/b!RqyfiVk0PEChr_1QI5evBXtL3K-WSdtKkyz6eja3xRBC6hrmzpkvQJj5dNPZ_nOX/items/01R25WNH7Z5WOF6ENPCZAYZHV7T4FKB57/uploadSession?

byte read going on
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://x.sharepoint.com/sites/PrivateMarket/_api/v2.0/drives/b!RqyfiVk0PEChr_1QI5evBXtL3K-WSdtKkyz6eja3xRBC6hrmzpkvQJj5dNPZ_nOX/items/01R25WNH7Z5WOF6ENPCZAYZHV7T4FKB57R/uploadSession?guid=%27311a1128-82b6-4c5a-b2a9-7dfec1ffebce%27&dc=0&tempauth=eyJ0}
Commit the upload session
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=501, message=Not Implemented, url=https://x.sharepoint.com/sites/PrivateMarket/_api/v2.0/drives/b!RqyfiVk0PEChr_1QI5evBXtL3K-WSdtKkyz6eja3xRBC6hrmzpkvQJj5dNPZ_nOX/items/01R25WNH7Z5WOF6ENPCZAYZHV7T4FKB57R/uploadSession?guid=%27311a1128-82b6-4c5a-b2a9-7dfec1ffebce%27&dc=0&tempauth=eyJ0e}
2024-01-28 20:29:59.893 ERROR 56168 --- [        Timer-0] org.ace.service.GraphAPIService          : Error while uploading file: C:\Users\x\Desktop\project\document\test\Query_Rept\x_depo_h_acc_map.sql
```